# How to add a scroll bar when the content of the div is overextended? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to do the following: I want when there is a lot of content in a div, instead of the div getting bigger, add a scroll bar to it. I show you a photo:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ShzE.png)

I want a scroll bar to appear in the previous div when there is a lot of it contained, right now what it does to me is that the div itself expands, and I don't want that. I have tried to use and but it does not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. fix height for the div, 2. overflow: scroll

Comment: I have made a mistake in putting the css tag in the question ... I am doing it with React Native and 'overflow-y' does not exist I think, on the other hand, I cannot give it a fixed height because the div has to be adjusted to size Of the device. Still, thanks for your reply.

Comment: hmm then you probably just need to use Scrollview. A fix height Scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `div` tags in `ReactNative`.
What you need is just to use a [ScrollView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview) component with appropriate height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use overflow:scroll for the minor div and keep the main div with the height and width that you need https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are looking for this I guess: Content will fill the height of parent box and as soon as it exceeds the parent heigh

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<span class="inner">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</span>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gv3jabm7/)